# MFC drawing board

Tags: c++, mfc

I made a heap on console. I've done all coding. Now I just need to show the heap tree on a drawing board. I am new to MFC and learned some basics like using a pDC pointer to draw nodes. Like `pDC->ellipse(int x,int x2,int y,int y2)`. However I don't get how I will be able to show a complete tree on the board.

```
void CAst3View::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CAst3Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if(a.control_draw == true)
    {
        pDC->Ellipse(100, 100 ,500,500);
    }
    //if    (a.height!=0)
    //{
    //  pDC->Ellipse(100, 100 ,500,500);
    //}
    // TODO: add draw code for native data here
}
```

This gives me one circle on the drawing board.

Comment: read question...wondered why formatting is so bad...suggest correcting it.

Comment: well i hope it is better now !!

Comment: @Haris - You draw an ellipse inside a square area, and it turns out that it looks like a circle. Is that the problem?

Comment: Could you explain better what you are asking?

Comment: @BoPersson: ellipse function is used in mfc to draw circles on board.ellipse(x,x2,y,y2) function is used to draw. i will just have to give coordinated in it . . .

Comment: @konrad: well iam supposed to make a heap tree. task includes taking height as input. based on it calculate num of nodes with formula. randomly generate value for each node . now convert this array into heap tree. i used array based structure to form tree . i have made the heap tree in array and now i just want to show the tree on drawing board of mfc.

Comment: tree as in like we say trees in c++ branched form. !! i hope am clear now!!

Comment: So the Ellipse is completely irrelevant to what you're trying to achieve? You just want to draw a tree graph with lines?

Comment: well iam thinking to use ellipse function to make a nodes at different coordinates and use lineto and moveto function to join the nodes and yess tree graph with lines is what i want to achieve . . . ellipse function used once will just give me a simple circle that is one node!!!

Comment: You need to calculate the location of each node in your tree. You could start at the top of the screen, move down a certain amount for each deeper dimension, and then draw the nodes at that depth. Then draw the lines connecting them. Really, this is quite basic, and I assume this is a school assignment - please ask more specific questions rather than having someone else do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

The `Ellipse` function is used to draw a circle. To draw a complete tree, you may need to change the x- and y- coordinates and keep drawing the circle, then connect each circle using the [`LineTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzc1344s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

Related post which may help you: [Tree Circle Draw Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29073/Tree-Circle-Draw-Control)